# jqgrid: How to display/add/edit records from multiple table?

Tags: database, jqgrid, multiple-tables

I am new to JqGrid and I know it works with single database table perfectly.

But my questions is, when dealing with multiple tables, especially for those with one-to-many association, what is the best practice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are trying to say "one to many association" in your scenario? Will you elaborate your question with some codes that you have tried, then only someone can help you?

Comment: If I understand u correctly, here is a tip. you can collaborate data from many tables, but this comes under database section. you can send that data to your jqGrid as JSON Data. For further ideas & help, you should tell us what database you using? what programming language? And what you tried (codes) for this scenario?